# Low FPS issues in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have finished the following function, It is containing 26 if else block in update. So it  reflects little drop in FPS.

I have checked the 26 object using dynamic casting.  Depend on shape, i checked the logic.

Here is the coding.

```
void WagonNode::update(float dt)
{
int found = 0;
for (int32 i = 0; i < kMaxContactPoints100 && found < contactPointCount100_; i++)
{
    ContactPoint100* point = contactPoints100_ + i;
    b2Fixture *otherFix = point->otherFixture;
    if( otherFix )
    {

        found++;
        b2Body *otherBody =  otherFix->GetBody();
        BodyNode *otherNode = (BodyNode*) otherBody->GetUserData();

        if (dynamic_cast<ShapeA*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("A"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeB*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("B"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeC*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("C"));
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeD*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("D"));
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeE*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("E"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeF*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("F"));
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeG*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("G"));
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeH*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {

            tagWord(CCString::create("H"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeI*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("I"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeJ*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("J"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeK*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("K"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeL*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
             tagWord(CCString::create("L"));

        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<ShapeM*>(otherNode) != NULL)
        {
            tagWord(CCString::create("M"));

        }

      etc...


    }
}
```

}

If there is any changes in the above coding, it would help me a lot.

Can any one assist me to handle or stabilise the FPS?

Comment: Dont use FPS on simulator as indicative of anything. measure on a device. Also, for these kinds of situation in obj-c (not certain you can in your context), i would carry a property in each of the Shape*, say "keyForTagWord" , a string, and then just use it. Trades space against time. Also useful for class factories.

Comment: Have you analyzed (profiled) the app and pinpointed the drop in fps to just this method? If not it would be pointless trying to optimize it. However I do see a problem: dynamic_cast is slow. Instead of dynamic casting encode this information in the shape itself, so you can access a "type" variable in the node. For example you could use CCNode's built-in "tag" property, or userData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic casting is slow and might be the problem here. In this case you could try using typeid to resolve the dynamic type:

example:

```
    if (typeid (*othernode) == typeid (ShapeA)) 
    {
      tagWord(CCString::create("A"));
    } elseif
    ...
```

Another thing is, you are creating potentially a lot of strings there, you might want to check if that causes the performance issues. Use a profiler to find out the actual bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  But no need pointer(*) in before othernode.